# Prestashop cart save not working

Tags: php, prestashop, cart, prestashop-1.6, carrier

i'm dealing with a problem, I need to change the carrier if the cart amount it > 500 , so , I'm hooking actionCartSave and checking the amount , but , when I do

```
$cart->id_carrier=(int)$carrier_id;
$cart->update();
```

The ajax stops responding , need to reload the page to see if a product has been added to the cart, but if i remove the `$cart->update()` , the carrier does not get updated. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are running into a loop. when you call `update`, the hook `actionCartSave` gets called again.
What you need to do is avoid updating the cart if the cart carrier is the same one as in your result

```
if ((int)$cart->id_carrier !== (int)$carrier_id) {
    $cart->id_carrier = (int)$carrier_id;
    $cart->update();
}
```

That way, you will avoid the infinite loop
Another (better) solution would be to use `$cart->save();` because it doesn't call `actionCartSave`